# Im working on an application using eclipse RCP. I have a graphical editor and I would like to draw a figure on it programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I do not want to use an editPart or have any connection with the model. An other solution that would work for me is to draw a figure that is out of bounds of its parent

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could get the `GraphicalViewer` of the editor, pull out the `LightweightSystem` and draw directly over it.

Since `GraphicalViewer` does not expose this directly (check [`GraphicalViewerImpl`](https://github.com/eclipse/gef-legacy/blob/4bd95e872fa4d5566361a8b19af3f2fb1b81351a/org.eclipse.gef/src/org/eclipse/gef/ui/parts/GraphicalViewerImpl.java) where it is protected) you would need to create your own implementation that does expose it.

Comment: I create the figure on a new layer whick seems to do what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Great to hear. Would be nice if you can set the answer as correct then